# How to conditionally add variables to a destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements, destructuring, sheetjs

I am building a function to export a JSON object to an Excel file with SheetJS. Before exorting the data, I need to filter it to include only certain fields/properties. I have a .map() method with a destructuring assignment that takes a number of arguments. Each argument is a field that should be filtered out from the JSON data before generating the report. Some fields are always filtered out, like "favourite" or "linkedinsummary" in the code below. But other fields, like "comments" should be filtered out only if the user has decided to not include it. My problem is that I can't figure out how to conditionally add certain fields to the destructuring assignment. I have tried the following:

```
//this filters out all the fields that should not appear in the report
    const filteredProfiles = transformedProfiles.map((profile) => {
        const {
            //Below: fields to filter out
            favourite,
            linkedinsummary,
            
            ...filteredProfile
        } = profile;

        const result = {...filteredProfile};

        //if the user has decided that "comments" should not be included, then add it to the 
        list above
        if (!store.state.userData.proptions.fields.comments) {
            result.comments = profile.comments;
        }

        return result;
    });
```

If I add "comments" to the list directly, it works, "comments" is left out. But with a conditional statement like above, "comments" is still exported to the report.

Comment: Deconstructors are radically different concept. What you're talking about is *destructuring assignment* which takes *structured* data and pulls it apart - de-structures it. Deconstruction is the opposite of construction - it's code that needs to run for an object to be *destroyed* as opposed to *created*. When the instance is being removed. Deconstructors don't really exist in JS - they can be found in other languages. C++ being a prominent one.

Comment: You cannot declare variables dynamically.

Comment: Thank you!. Maybe this way isn't the most relevant then. How can I filter out the transformedProfiles array with a variable number of fields to exclude base on the user selection? For ex. "favourite" and "linkedinsummary" should always be filtered out. But "comments" should be filtered out only if store.state.userData.proptions.fields.comments is false.

Comment: @jeff3546 ... The OP should edit the original question and make the new requirement from the above comment part of that question.

Comment: @jeff3546 ... Is this correct? ... `if (!store.state.userData.proptions.fields.comments) {result.comments = profile.comments;}` ... which generically translates to ... _"Whenever `fields` does not have a certain property or the property's value is either **`false`** or otherwise **falsy**, it has to be assigned from `profile` to `result`."_ ... Or in other words ... _"Whatever **truthy** property name is carried by `fields`, its related key/property has to be deleted from `result`."_

Comment: @jeff3546 ... Regarding the so far provided sole answer / approach are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's last comment ...

> *"... How can I filter out the `transformedProfiles` array with a variable number of fields to exclude base on the user selection? For ex. `favourite` and `linkedinsummary` should always be filtered out. But `comments` should be filtered out only if `store.state.userData.proptions.fields.comments` is false."* – jeff3546

... and from one of my above comments ...

> _@jeff3546 ... Is this correct? ... `if (!store.state.userData.proptions.fields.comments) {result.comments = profile.comments;}` ... which generically translates to ... *"Whenever `fields` does not have a certain property or the property's value is either **`false`** or otherwise **falsy**, it has to be assigned from `profile` to `result`."* ... Or in other words ... *"Whatever **truthy** property name is carried by `fields`, its related key/property has to be deleted from `result`."*

In case the above is correct then the OP's provided example code changes to a generic implementation similar to the next provided one ...

```
const listOfDismissedKeys = Object
 .entries(store.state.userData.proptions.fields)
 //.filter(([key, value]) => value !== false)
 //.filter(([key, value]) => value === true)
 .filter(([key, value]) => !!value)
 .map(([key]) => key);

const filteredProfiles = transformedProfiles
  .map(profile => {
    const { favourite, linkedinsummary, ...result } = profile;
    listOfDismissedKeys
      .forEach(key =>
        Reflect.deleteProperty(result, key)
      );
    return result;
  });
```